# How to use OrderedDict from DataStructures package in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to install and use the DataStructures package and it doesn't seem to be working; or I am missing something.

```
Pkg.init()
Pkg.status()
Pkg.add("DataStructures")
Pkg.status()
Pkg.update()
d = OrderedDict(Char,Int)
ERROR: OrderedDict not defined
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you didn't get any errors you didn't mention, then you *installed* the package.  Now you have to let Julia know you want to use it:

```
julia> using DataStructures

julia> d = OrderedDict{Char,Int}()
DataStructures.OrderedDict{Char,Int32}()

julia> d['a'] = 9

julia> d
['a'=>9]
```

If you'd prefer not to clutter the scope, you could use `import` instead:

```
julia> import DataStructures

julia> DataStructures.OrderedDict{Char, Int8}()
DataStructures.OrderedDict{Char,Int8}()
```

or

```
julia> import DataStructures: OrderedDict
```

instead.  Reading the [Modules](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/modules/) section of the manual might be helpful.

Comment: `OrderedDict` is now in `OrderedCollections` https://github.com/JuliaCollections/OrderedCollections.jl